# Profile modular dotemacs

Tags: emacs, profiling, dot-emacs

My emacs is modular (and uses ~20 loads in `init.el`). I want to speed up my start time. I know of http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ProfileDotEmacs, but that isn't allowing me to dive into my config deeper. How can I profile it to a finer level?

Comment: You may bisect the .emacs file repeatedly  and see which routine causes the problem and do profiling.